# Mediawiki extension error

Tags: command-line, php, mysql, mediawiki

I'm running the latest version of mediawiki using MoWeS Portable II from my desktop. I just installed this extension on the wiki http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MsUpload

It adds an option to upload files (to be embedded in an article) to the edit screen of an article. After installing it when I try and edit an article I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method OutputPage::addModules() in
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\knowledge mapedia 10 25 13
> copy\mowes_portable\www\mediawiki\extensions\MsUpload\msupload.php on
> line 65

### Also here is what I posted in the localsettings.php file (I put it in at the end of localsettings.php if it makes a difference):

### Start --------------------------------------- MsUpload

$wgMSU_ShowAutoKat = false;     #autocategorisation
$wgMSU_CheckedAutoKat = false;  #checkbox for autocategorisation checked
$wgMSU_debug = false;           #debug mode
$wgMSU_ImgParams = '400px';     #default max-size for inserted image
$wgMSU_UseDragDrop = true;      #show drag&drop area
require_once "$IP/extensions/MsUpload/msupload.php";

### End  --------------------------------------- MsUpload

require_once "$IP/extensions/msupload/msupload.php";

---

### At line 65 in the localsettings.php file there is the following:

line 64 ## Database settings

line 65 $wgDBtype           = "mysql";

line 66 $wgDBserver         = "localhost";

line 67 $wgDBname           = "mediawiki";

line 68 $wgDBuser           = "root";

line 69 $wgDBpassword       = "";

---

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be related to [this answer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Extension_talk:ArticleFeedback/Fatal_error:_Call_to_undefined_method_OutputPage::addModules%28%29_in_/var/lib/mediawiki/extensions/ClickTracking/ClickTracking.hooks.php_on_line_73/reply) on a talk page of MediaWiki:

> The various methods with "module" in their name (i.e. OutputPage::addModules(), OutputPage::addModuleStyles(), OutputPage::addModuleScripts(), etc.) were introduced with ResourceLoader, so they most certainly aren't present in 1.15. I'd suggest upgrading your wiki to 1.18

So, try to upgrade MW to a version >= 1.18.